# Predictive analysis based on history

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, prediction

Let me first say that I am a CS person and my knowledge about statistics is quite basic. I am trying to see what predictive analysis to use for a problem I am trying to solve. I will try to make my problem general also so that anyone can benefit from the question. Basically, I have a group of objects that I am watching over a certain period of time. By the end of that period, some objects remain unchanged, other objects are modified by a small amount, while other ones change completely. I am trying to look at a small history of these objects and predict how they will change in the future. I want to identify what are the parameters that affect their future behavior and how they affect their future behavior. I dont know what part of statistics should I look into. I think it is important to say that the outcome is discrete. I want to classify those objects into "stable", "change by a small value", or completely change.

Comment: You might have over-generalized your problem to the point where a good answer would have to cover most of statistics and data mining. Why don't you just ask the question you actually have?

Comment: This is almost my problem. Instead of objects, I actually have memory pages. Each memory page is 4K. In a period of five minutes, some of these pages will change completely. Others will stay the same. Others will change by a little bit. I want to classify pages into three categories. I have a second by second data of the whole memory for the whole five minutes. So I do know how the pages will change. I was wondering if I can look into a shorter amount of time. Lets say three seconds and be able to predict what category this page will fall into.

Comment: Is there something special about these three categories? Or, if you could, would you prefer to predict *how much* the pages will change or *when* they change?  In short, sharing some sense of why you want to do this will help generate useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

The main portion of your question can be answered by : Investigate ARMA models which can be useful to analyze and predict a time series.  Arbitrary classification is yet another matter. One would have to specify the classification rules and the use the forecasts vis-a-vis recent values in order to bucket the series into your three classes.